# iOS - Property not found on object of type X - inherited property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a CoreData-based app. In Core Data, I have an entity called ZSProduction which creates an NSManagedObject subclass called ZSProductionCD. This is the .h file created.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface ZSProductionCD : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * appVersion;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id highlightColour;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastUpdated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * notes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * owner;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * productionID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * productionName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * scenesLocked;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * shotNumberingStyle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sortIndex;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * tagline;

@end
```

I then subclass this with a class called ZSProduction:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ZSProductionCD.h"

@interface ZSProduction : ZSProductionCD
@end
```

The reason for subclassing is that I am likely to add a bunch of methods & possibly other properties. This way, if I make changes to the entity, I can write out a new ZSProductionCD class without affecting what I've done with ZSProduction.

Now here's the problem. I'm using ZSProduction in a view controller. But I'm having a problem with just one of the properties.

In this view controller, I declare a property:

```
#import "ZSProduction.h"

@interface [...]
@property (strong, nonatomic) ZSProduction *item;
@end
```

And then later, in a method:

```
self.productionNameField.text = self.item.productionName;
self.shotNumStyleControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [self.item.shotNumberingStyle intValue];
```

And that's where it goes wrong. XCode complains:

Property 'shotNumberingStyle' not found on object of type 'ZSProduction *'

Note that it doesn't complain about the productionName property, which works fine.

In the same view controller, if I use:

```
self.item.shotNumberingStyle = 0;
```

Then I get the same error. But if I use:

```
[self.item setValue:0 forKey:@"shotNumberingStyle"];
```

Then it works fine. Yet I can use:

```
self.item.highlightColour = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

with no problem at all. What gives?

Any clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I sorted the problem, but I thought I'd leave this here in case someone else has something similar.

I realised that the three properties that were being inherited okay, and were accessible, wee ones I'd created in an earlier version of the ZSProduction class - one that didn't use Core Data (I'm currently refactoring to move from archives to CD).

It turned out that there were old ZSProduction.h and ZSProduction.m files on the disk, in the project subdir - but not in XCode. Seems that XCode was looking at these. The old files were in the root dir for the project, while the newer files were in a subdir (called 'Model'). I deleted the old files, restarted XCode & all is now tickety-boo.